Is changing the url of the popup page normal while making chrome extension?
Ok I building an extension where I need different UI in my popup based on different actions. So I am changing the href to the page using following
window.location.href = "/html/result.html" + redirectParameters;

The extension was originally in manifest v2 and now I am converting it to manifest version 3. So what happens is tht when these pages I get error
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
So I just want to ask you is it considered normal or I should put everthing in one popup.html and then use classes to hide/show?
Using this way effects the communication of popup with other parts like background and content script?

It's ok to change location, but your messaging code is apparently incorrect, judging by the error. Note that changing the URL destroys the previous page and its message ports.
